# Unable to change options for ngx_pagespeed

Tags: nginx, mod-pagespeed, nginx-module

I was able to successfully add ngx_pagespeed to my Nginx server at Digital Ocean. I did an automated install per this: https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/build_ngx_pagespeed_from_source

The module works - for example I can see it is automatically converting my .jpg images to .webp. Also, `curl -I -p http://localhost| grep X-Page-Speed` returns the `X-Page-Speed: 1.13.35.2-0` header.

However, I’m **not able to edit any options**. When I try to run something like `pagespeed rewrite_images on`, or even `pagespeed on`, I get an error `pagespeed: command not found`.

Per documentation `pagespeed` should be the command for Nginx: https://modpagespeed.com/doc/configuration

I tried a couple of other commands:

1. `whereis pagespeed` returns `pagespeed:`
2. `which pagespeed` returns nothing.

As far as I know these should be returning the full path, something like `/usr/bin/pagespeed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that for some reason I thought pagespeed flags were turned on/off via terminal commands. This assumption is wrong. It actually needs to be done as Nginx directives, added to nginx.conf file and restart the Nginx server.